# Referencing Variables with for loops

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python, and was wondering whether anybody could help me with the following problem:

I am trying to map a Christmas tree after receiving an input from the user about the tree's height and base branch length. Here is the code I currently have:

```
tree_map_5 = ['B']
tree_map_4 = ['B']
tree_map_3 = ['B']
tree_map_2 = ['B']
tree_map_1 = ['B']
# (B means Bark (For the trunk))

Layers = int(input("\nHow many layers will your christmas tree have? (Maximum 5)\n\nInput: "))
Base_Branch_Length = int(input("\nHow long will the base branches of your tree be? (in centimetres)\n\nInput: "))

for i in range (Layers):
  for j in range (Base_Branch_Length+1):
    tree_map_'i'.append(0)
    tree_map_'i'.insert(0, 0)
```

If the user were to say 5 layers and 5 base branch length, the lists would show this:

```
tree_map_5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
tree_map_4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
tree_map_3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
tree_map_2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
tree_map_1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I was wondering whether I would be able to write a for loop that adds noughts into a changeable number of lists (like I tried to do) depending on the number of layers they input.

Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Thanks

Comment: I think you don't know that you can have multidimensional lists, aka. lists in lists. Also please edit you question and surround your code with triple backticks (\`\`\`) so it can be more readable.

Comment: Have the `tree_map` variables as one list instead, then just append to the list to add layers.

Comment: Creating variables iteratively is considered bad practice (might easily lead to problems), so it's better to use dictionaries or lists to store your variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answers - sorry for the badly formatted question (I'm new to Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this article](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) to get a grasp at dynamic variable names. Like the article already warns you, you shouldn't want to have dynamic variable bames. If you **insist** on it, in your for loop you should replace the **.append(0)** and **.insert(0, 0)** respectively by the following:

```
globals()['tree_map_{}'.format(i)].append(0)
globals()['tree_map_{}'.format(i)].insert(0, 0)
```

But a better solution would be to use one big list:

```
Layers = int(input("\nHow many layers will your christmas tree have? (Maximum 5)\n\nInput: "))
Base_Branch_Length = int(input("\nHow long will the base branches of your tree be? (in centimetres)\n\nInput: "))

tree_map = [['B'] for i in range(Layers)]

for i in range (Layers):
  for j in range (Base_Branch_Length+1):
    tree_map[i].append(0)
    tree_map[i].insert(0, 0)

print(tree_map[0])
```

Comment: That is indeed what the article is about. I edited my answer a bit.